# How columns/objects are created on indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am quite new to indexedDB, and started to create a Database to transfer WebSQL.

What I would like to know is how fields are created in indexedDB.

For example:

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMPRESULTENTRIES ( "
    + " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + " instid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES institutions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, "
    + " qid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES questionnaires(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, "
    + " result TEXT NOT NULL )");
```

How would I create the same table in indexedDB. I am kind of confused about this part of indexedDB. 
Currently I am creating only keypath with id:

```
db.createObjectStore("TEMPRESULTENTRIES", {keypath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
```

And I am wondering how to add, or when will the other fields be created?

From a small testcase, I can see that I can just create Columns/Objects in Store when I anm populating table/Store, as:

```
store.put({ObjectName: Value});
```

Is it the correct way to create Objects in the stores?

Best, Amry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IndexedDB is an object-oriented database, not a relational database. The closest analog to SQL tables is object stores, created with `IDBDatabase.createObjectStore`. Object stores don't have a fixed schema, so a call to `IDBObjectStore.put` can accept objects with any fields so long as the object has a `keyPath` field or the `keyPath` is made optional by setting `{autoIncrement: true}`. By default, you can only query for documents using the `keyPath`. To query documents using other fields, an index must be created using `IDBObjectStore.createIndex`

This is an excerpt from an application that looks up contacts using a prefix of number or name.

```
dbReq.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
    var db = event.target.result,
        objectStore = db.createObjectStore('calls', {keyPath: 'timestamp'}),
        contactStore = db.createObjectStore('contacts', {autoIncrement: true});

    objectStore.createIndex('number', 'number', {unique: false});
    contactStore.createIndex('number', 'number');
    contactStore.createIndex('name', 'name', {unique: false});
    objectStore.createIndex('timestamp', 'timestamp', {unique: true});
};
```

Find by prefix:

```
findPrefix: function(prefix, fn) {
    var transaction = this.db.transaction(['contacts', 'calls']),
        contactStore = transaction.objectStore('contacts'),
        callStore = transaction.objectStore('calls'),
        numberIndex = callStore.index('number'),
        nameIndex = contactStore.index('name'),
        key = IDBKeyRange.bound(prefix, prefix + '\uffff'),
        times = 0,
        result = [],
        consume = function(records) {
            result = result.concat(records);
            if (++times === 2) {
                /* Remove duplicate numbers: names and numbers may have the same value*/
                var numbers = {};
                result = result.filter(function(contact) {
                    if (!numbers[contact.number]) {
                        return (numbers[contact.number] = true);
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                fn(result);
            }
        };

    this.consumeCursor(numberIndex.openCursor(key, 'nextunique'), consume);
    this.consumeCursor(nameIndex.openCursor(key), consume);
}
```

[More on IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

Comment: So to have other object fields, I need to create keypath first for that when creating ObjectStore? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, there can be at most one `keyPath` field in an object store. The `keyPath` field is used for looking up objects and must be unique. You can add objects with any fields to an object store without reshaping your object store.  That is, `objectStore.put({keyPathField: 1, f1: 2, f2: 3})` and `objectStore.put({keyPathField: 2, g1: [1,3], g2: 3})` are both allowed. If you don't have any indexes on the fields, you can only look up your object store using the `keyPath` field's value: `IDBObjectStore.get(2)` will yield `{keyPathField: 2, g1: [1,3], g2: 3}`

Comment: Thanks for clarification. If you can answer, can I create several objectstores on onupgradeneeded function? When I am creating database, and objectstores for the first time?

Comment: I just checked, and so far I can create several stores. If there is something you can add about it, feel free to comment. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. I have added an excerpt from one of my applications. It creates two object stores on `onupgradeneeded`, queries both of them and filters the result. The `findPrefix` method looks up a contact by either its name or number.

Comment: I did not know one could open two stores for transactions, and without any read or write modes. Or do I miss here something?

Comment: Transactions can span across multiple object stores and if a read/write mode isn't specified, it defaults to read